# Accessing 'data' attributes of a dynamically loaded object?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm having some trouble accessing the data attributes of a dynamically(ajax) loaded file.

For example I might load a file that has a result:

```
<div id="blah" class="hello" data-something="or_other" />
```

And then do the jquery:

```
var blah_id = $('#id').attr('id'),
    blah_class = $('#blah').attr('class'),
    blah_something = $('#blah').data('something');
```

I end up with:

```
   blah_id === 'blah';
   blah_class === 'hello';
   blah_something === null;
```

I know the html is ok, because if I take this result and put it on the page before doing a ajax call I get everything I need.

Is there something special about data attributes I don't understand?

**UPDATE**
I have noticed that the dynamically loaded file actually prints out the data attribute - ie. *it is visible* in the printed html. To my knowledge its not supposed to be visible in the html, and when it works on a statically loaded page it is *invisible* in the printed html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's weird, [seems to work here](http://jsfiddle.net/mgs3c/1/). The [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method tries to parse the value and convert it to the underlying type:

For example:

```
<div data-role="page" data-last-value="43" data-hidden="true" data-options='{"name":"John"}'></div>

$("div").data("role") === "page";
$("div").data("lastValue") === 43;
$("div").data("hidden") === true;
$("div").data("options").name === "John";
```

Comment: That is weird. very cool though I didn't know you could do an ajax test on jsfiddle :)

Comment: @cosmicbdog, if the `data-*` attribute contains `-` you should use camelCase to query it.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've kept it a simple string without any underscores or dashes. But I've just updated the question because the dynamically loaded data attribute is visible in the result when I don't think its supposed to be.

Comment: @cosmicbdog, I don't understand what you mean when you say that the *dynamically loaded data attribute is visible in the result*. Maybe your HTML is invalid? Could you provide a http://jsfiddle.net illustrating the problem?

Comment: Sorry, the result is <div data-field="etc"></div> but if you're too look at the source of this you would actually just see <div></div> because the data attributes are hidden - correct? However in my ajax result, I can see the 'data-field="etc"'. That shouldn't be the way it works.

Comment: @cosmicbdog, if the result is `<div data-field="etc"></div>` and you inject this result into the DOM, you could use FireBug or Chrome Developer Toolbar and you should be able to see the data attribute.